# TinyMCE: How to get rid of some buttons

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm trying to make a minimal implementation of TinyMCE. The only buttons I want are bold, italic, font size, font color, links and undo/redo.

I've trimmed the example from their fiddle demo, and I've been able to remove many of the undesired buttons.

This is what I've reduced the init to, but I don't see what else I could possibly eliminate. Is there a separate config I failed to find? With this, I still get list buttons, super/subscript and remove formatting and insert special character...

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "", //note, i've removed every plugin for demnstration, stll have unwanted buttons

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "|,bold,italic,|,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    theme_advanced_text_colors : "FF00FF,FFFF00,000000",
    width: "100%",
    height: "400"
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the theme options, you can enter what you want to have disabled by using `theme_advanced_disable`. For example to get rid of the subscript and superscript buttons, add the following code:

```
theme_advanced_disable : "sup,sub"
```

Comment: Here's a list of all of them too FlavorScape:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Buttons/controls

Comment: thanks kiddies! I'm normally a raw coder and shy away from libs, but TinyMCE is danged nice!

Comment: yeah, that would be a really annoying wheel to re-invent

Answer (score 4):

*This comment was addressing TinyMCE 3.X*

You need to empty out the second (an possibly third) set of buttons

```
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
//etc
```

*TinyMCE 4.*

The default toolbar in V4 only seems to have a single set of buttons so the above answer for 3. is a bit misleading. In V4, if you don't specify a toolbar, it'll build one for you.

To set what buttons show up in a toolbar, just specify what items you want.

Single toolbar

```
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter
```

Multiple Toolbars

```
toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
toolbar2: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
```

OR

```
toolbar: [
    "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
 ]
```

Official Docs:

- Toolbar [http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:toolbar](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atoolbar)
- List of buttons: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Controls

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the plugins in the code snippet you mentioned. Just remove what you don't need, and it should adjust.

Comment: err, if you saw my original list, there's nothing that looked like bullets... I can remove all plugins and still have buttons.